# Any way to ensure return of control to invoking Activity, after call disconnection in Dialer started with ACTION_CALL

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, telephony

Here is how I start the system Dialer activity to make a phone call, from MyOwnActivity:

```
String callee = "5556666";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + callee));
startActivity(intent);
```

The call is placed as expected and once I touch the disconnect button to end the call, the control doesn't return to MyOwnActivity, but it switches to the Contact browsing Activity of the system Dialer. This was unexpected, and I am trying to figure out, if there is a deterministic way to ensure that control returns to MyOwnActivity.

This behavior is observed both on a real device and on emulator.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to figure out, if there is a deterministic way to ensure that control returns to MyOwnActivity

Build your own ROM mod that contains a dialer that reliably returns control to whatever activity started it.

The dialer is not your app. It is somebody else's app. The developers of that app are free to do whatever they want. And since the dialer seems to be modified on just about every device, the behavior of one device's dialer will differ from another device's dialer.

Comment: Argh ! Okay, thanks for that. I had assumed that the Dialer behaviour is consistent across devices. In any case, building my own ROM won't help (other than experiment), as question from standpoint of developing an app for a specific purpose.